# Good way to get list of keys of the n highest value of a List Tuple

Tags: c#, list, linq, dictionary, tuples

I have a sample List Tuple:

```
    List<Tuple<string, int>> List = new List<Tuple<string, int>>();
    List.Add(new Tuple<string, int>(storage, 3));
    List.Add(new Tuple<string, int>(battery, 2));
    List.Add(new Tuple<string, int>(hover, 1));
```

How will I get the first 2 or n keys with the highest value and add those keys in a list?

Comment: A `List` has no keys. Do you mean to find first n elements whose `Item2` has highest value?

Answer (score 4):

Using LINQ, you could let

```cs
var l = newCollection2.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value).Take(2).Select(x => x.Key).ToList();
```

[.NET Fiddle example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zHDV9I).

Comment: Hi i changed my implementation, I know use List Tuple, would that be applicable?

Comment: @DevMaker: Sure, just use `.Item1` and `.Item2` instead of `.Key` and `.Value` respectively.

Comment: @DevMaker, im getting an error when I use .Item2. It says "Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1061 'List<Tuple<string, int>>' does not contain a definition for 'Item2' and no extension method 'Item2' accepting a first argument of type 'List<Tuple<string, int>>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 
"

Comment: You should be using it on the elements; not the entire list. See https://dotnetfiddle.net/ty9IWE

Comment: @DevMaker: Also, C# now has the handy new [ValueTuples (TutorialsTeacher)](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/valuetuple).